# Rotating a captured video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-capture

My app takes a video capture from the front camera and saves it to SD.
Although the preview is just fine (after being rotated 90 degrees), the end result is tilt sideways.

Is there a way to save it properly?

Comment: Do you want to (a) rotate camera input as it's being recorded, (b) do a second pass that rotates the video, or (c) rotate a video for playback? What API are you using for capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being user for the recording? In case is it MediaRecorder take a look at the method [`setOrientationHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29) and set it accordingly.

Comment: Yes that function looks like what I need. I will test it out soon and accept your answer if applicable.  Thanks